# Nested table's wide is not changeable

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles when changing the wide in nested table.

```
<table width="80%" id="parent">
<tbody>
     <tr>
         <th>
             <table id="samples">
                 <tbody>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 <tr><th>sample_path_01</th> <th> tagging </th></tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </th>
         <th>
             Screenshot
         </th>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I'd like to make table `samples`'s wide as wider as the first `th` in the `parent`, but I can't do that.

I use `CSS` to set the width argument, and the full code is :

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/7XFfM/)

Comment: What do you mean by wilde? Do you mean width?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, it's `width`. I edited the original post.

Comment: Do you really need a nested table?

Comment: id="parent" is misspelled in your jsfiddle code (not the solution, just pointing that out)

Comment: @misterManSam I'd like to make the left cell scrollable and nested table is the only way that I know to complete this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what result you are trying to achieve, but would something like this be a nicer, simpler alternative?

Have a fiddle! - [Fiddle link!](http://jsfiddle.net/7tqvt/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="samplesParent">
    <table id="samples">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>sample_path_01</td>
                <td>tagging</td>
            </tr>
    <!-- to infinity -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div>Screenshot</div>
```

CSS

```
#samplesParent {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#samples {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: using `<div>` is brilliant way to solve my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/7XFfM/3/) to think about- everything in divs.

HTML

```
<div id='holderdiv'>
  <div id='scrolldiv'>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
    <div class='leftdiv'>sample_path_01</div><div class='rightdiv'>tagging</div>
  </div>
  <div id='screendiv'>Screenshot</div>
  </div>
</div>
```